# spring web flow: set a dropdown list dynamically on child view using parent name

Tags: spring, jquery, web, workflow

I am new to spring web flow. I am trying to load a dropdown list on a view(child) dynamically based on the value / values set from the previous(parent) view.

So a list of agents are selected from a view and then on clicking 'next' a dropdown of players will be loaded for each of those agents.  So if there are three agents, there dropdown boxes will show up and the list of players corrsponding to those three agents will be populated. My service method accepts a string and returns an arraylIst of player names

public List getPlayersForAgent(String agentName);

So what I am trying to do is when the child(player) view is loaded (i.e. user clicks next on agent view) there players dropdowns will be populated (i,e, the service method will be called three times with different agent name).  How do you pass a paameter and load a dropdown list dynamcally in spring web flow.  Is this possible using  jquery ajax call?